# Select latest post from each categories

Tags: mysql, sql

Am trying to get the latest post from each category of post ordered by the date, i tried this but its not giving the latest post from the table and when i use 'order by' before 'group by', the post are not ordered by date using mysql.

`SELECT post_id, category, author_id, title, article, time FROM (SELECT * FROM blog_post GROUP BY category LIMIT 0,5 ) AS timePost ORDER BY time DESC`

`SELECT post_id, category, author_id, title, article, time FROM (SELECT * FROM blog_post ORDER BY date LIMIT 0,5 ) AS timePost GROUP BY category`

Comment: can you please tell me sql or mysql

Comment: which database type are you using? oracle, mysql, sql-server, ....

Comment: mysql, i wrote it in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving the last record in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group)

Answer (score 1):

You can do **self join**.

```
   SELECT T1.`post_id`,
           T1.`category`,
            T1.`author_id`,
             T1.`title`, 
             T1.`article`,
              T1.`time` 
    FROM
            blog_post T1
            INNER JOIN
            (SELECT MAX(`time`) AS `time`,`category` FROM blog_post GROUP BY category) T2
         ON T1.`category` = T2.`category` AND T1.`time` = T2.`time`
  ORDER BY T1.`time` DESC
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

IN MS SQL as your question is not clear as per my assumption

```
SELECT post_id, category, author_id, title, article, time
FROM blog_post t
WHERE 
 t.post_id=(SELECT TOP 1 post_id
          FROM Table t2
          WHERE 
           t.post_id=t2.post_id
          ORDER BY time DESC)
```

Answer (score -1):

This seem to have work... i dont know how efficient it is though

`SELECT post_id, category, author_id, title, article, time 
FROM (SELECT * FROM blog_post ORDER BY time DESC ) 
AS timePost GROUP BY category ORDER BY time DESC`

Comment: This will display all the posts, but you need the latest one only?